# Can I nest an element inside a form's select tag?

Tags: html, css, forms, select

I'm looking to add a colour swatch next to a bunch of colour options, ie...

Markup:

```
<select class="form-control required" name="stripe-form-color">
    <option>Pacific Blue <span class="blue"></span></option> </select>
```

CSS:

```
form select span {
    margin-left: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

form .blue {
    background: #27a9d4;
}
```

When I try this, and check the source, the span isn't showing up in the select element.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: That's what made sense to me, but I've also tried divs, to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The only elements allowed inside a `select` tag are `option` and `optgroup`. If you've ever taken a good look at `selects` you'll notice that browsers take complete control over the styling; you'll only see pure, unstyled, black text inside a `select`. If you've seen something else, it wasn't a native select.

So you'll need to use a custom solution to achieve your desired goal. You could try something like [jQuery.chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), or attempt to build your own.

Comment: @EricBrockman no worries. Give this a go, and if you need help building the solution, simply ask another question :). I'd recommend leaving this question as-is because it's a good question.